# Desplegar archivo WAR usando Tomcat en un dominio externo

Tags: php, java, web, apache, tomcat

gracias por leerme y tratar de ayudarme :)

Estoy peleándome contra este problema muchos días ... Tengo un archivo WAR que quiero implementar en un dominio externo usando Tomcat.

He cambiado el puerto a 80 y he añadido esto:

```
<Host name = "www.extremadurainv.unex.es" appBase = "webapps"   
unpackWARs = "true" autoDeploy = "true" xmlValidation = "false"   
xmlNamespaceAware = "false"> <Alias> extremadurainv.unex.es/spinav 
</Alias> </host>
```

Pero cuando intento acceder a la página web, aparece el siguiente error:

> 403 Prohibido No tiene permiso para acceder a / spinav en este
>   servidor.

Entonces, ¿tengo que cambiar algo en el servidor Apache? ¿O es solo un problema de Tomcat?

Muchas gracias por su atención!

Comment: No debes cambiar el puerto del tomcat, lo que tienes que hacer es usar la redirección del apache al tomcat. Aquí - https://serverfault.com/questions/141904/forwarding-apache-requests-port-80-to-tomcat-port-8080 tienes algo de info